# Find path to a program (sqlcmd) installed by child subinstaller of Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

In my scenario I need to run .sql script at the end of my setup with `sqlcmd.exe`. But each version of SQL Server uses different paths for `sqlcmd`.

I'm trying some solutions to use `sqlcmd` but none work.
As a last test I created an installer just to run my script but even this doesn't recognize `sqlcmd` as a command.
Is there a way to retrieve the `sqlcmd` path with a function in order to pass the value to `[Run]` section?
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks

This is my code I'm trying

Main installer.exe

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin

[Files]
; sql server 2019 Express 
Source: "..\PREREQUIREMENTS\SQL\SQLSERVER\2019\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe"; \
    DestDir: "{tmp}"; DestName: "SQLSERVER2019.exe"; Flags: ignoreversion; \
    MinVersion: 10.0.17134; Tasks: SQL
; sql server 2014 Express 
Source: "..\PREREQUIREMENTS\SQL\SQLSERVER\2014\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe"; \
    DestDir: "{tmp}"; DestName: "SQLSERVER2014SP3.exe"; Flags: ignoreversion; \
    OnlyBelowVersion: 10.0.17134; Tasks: SQL
; sql management studio 18 
Source: "..\PREREQUIREMENTS\SQL\SSMS\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; \
    DestName: "SSMS18.exe"; Flags: ignoreversion; Tasks: SSMS
; SQLCMD
Source: "src\DB\ADM_DB_installer.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: ignoreversion; \
    Components: ADM
```

ADM_DB_installer.exe

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin

[Run]
Filename: "sqlcmd.exe"; \
    Parameters: "-v ADMPRIMARY=""{code:GetSQLVar|DBPATH}"" ADMDATA=""{code:GetSQLVar|DBPATH}"" ADMINDEX=""{code:GetSQLVar|DBPATH}"" ADMLOG=""{code:GetSQLVar|DBPATH}"" -S {code:GetSQLVar|SQLSERVER}\{code:GetSQLVar|INSTANCE} -U sa -P {code:GetSQLVar|SAPWD} -i ""{tmp}\CREATE_ADM_DB_1.0.0.sql"" -o ""{code:GetSQLVar|DBPATH}\log.txt"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better solution, but what you can do is to read the `PATH` from registry and use [`FileSearch`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_filesearch) to find the program.

```
[Run]
Filename: "{code:FileSearchInPath|sqlcmd.exe}"; Parameters: "..."
```

```pascal
[Code]
const
  EnvironmentKey = 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment';

function FileSearchInPath(FileName: string): string;
var
  Path: string;
begin
  Result := '';
  if not RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, EnvironmentKey, 'PATH', Path) then
  begin
    Log('Cannot read PATH');
  end
    else
  begin
    Log(Format('PATH is %s', [Path]));
    Result := FileSearch(FileName, Path);
    if Result = '' then
    begin
      Log(Format('Cannot find %s', [FileName]));
    end
      else
    begin
      Log(Format('Found %s', [Result]));
    end;
  end;

  if Result = '' then Result := FileName; // let it fail later
end;
```

The above code searches only system `PATH`, not user `PATH`.

*You do not need a separate installer to execute the `sqlcmd.exe`.*